# Stabilizing a Drone

Tags: quadcopter, imu

I have my IMU and I can get `attitude` (pitch, roll, yaw) as well as `gyro` (x, y, z)

As far as I can tell, `attitude` is all I need to stabilize my drone.

Is there any reason to implement `gyro` or will `attitude` suffice?

-- EDIT --

It seems the benefit of `gyro` is an immediate response to an outside factor effecting drone stability.

Example:
A gust of wind hits your `drone`. The `attitude` will not be quick enough combat the effects of wind. As far as I can tell, the gyro will be the best way to combat extreme wobble and outside influences such as wind / tether (leash).

-- EDIT 2 --

It's been a while since I posted this but I should add in that I ended up leveraging the infamous [PID algo](https://www.hackster.io/ElvisWolcott/drone-basics-pid-83da06) for my arduino.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gyro is needed to stabilize angular acceleration. Knowing only your `attitude`, drone doesn't know how fast on which axis is rotating, knows only where is gravity vector. `Gyro` gives you feedback on angular acceleration and that's what gives your drone stability.

Also, you can use only `gyro` in your drone, it will stabilize movement, but won't get back to horizontal flight/hovering position (depending if You are building multicopter or plane).

To fully stabilize your drone flight, you should use both `gyro` and `attitude`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Gyro was missing, I needed it on all axis.